# oracle sql query for selecting Even number columns

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, where-clause

In oracle sql when I am trying to get the output for the below, it is throwing error.

```
select city,id from station where id % 2 = 0;
```

Error:

```
ORA-00911: invalid character
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
           letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
           character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
           any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
           (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
           delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
           Reference Manual.
```

Answer (score 4):

The `%` operator for modulo is not supported in Oracle. You would need to use [function `mod()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions088.htm):

```
select city,id from station where mod(id, 2) = 0;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6a68d837fbeb3e18cd2f42abdb50dcb4)**

Comment: Great, It worked, Thank you so much ,, I have another question related to date of birth, will post the question shortly

Comment: Hello  could you please help me with the below query?

I have a table STUDENT with the below structure:

describe student;

Name Type

SNO NUMBER(2)
SNAME VARCHAR2(15) DOB DATE
AGE NUMBER(2)
TNO NUMBER(2)

Now while inserting the data in DOB column, getting error

INSERT INTO STUDENT (SNO,SNAME,DOB,AGE,TNO) VALUES ('42','IRONMAN','01-01-1991','29','1');

ERROR: error report: SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month 01843. 00000 - "not a valid month"

PLZ HELP

Comment: @Jack looks like you need to supply a `date` for DOB, not `'01-01-1991'`. See [the SQL Language docs for date literal syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1).